# Why "ruby-install ruby" fails with: "E: Couldn't find package build-essential"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-install

I've installed [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) like this:

```
brew install ruby-install
```

But, when I try to install ruby it fails:

```
$ ruby-install ruby
>>> Installing ruby 2.1.1 into /Users/mishamoroshko/.rubies/ruby-2.1.1 ...
>>> Installing dependencies for ruby 2.1.1 ...
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package build-essential
!!! Installing dependencies failed!
```

I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` first? Then have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/398489/how-to-install-build-essential

Comment: @lucke84: `sudo apt-get update` completely fails: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1893981/Screenshots/mfe3.png
(I think `apt-get` is not used much on OSX. Should I try and uninstall it, or it's probably not a good idea if it comes with OSX?)

Comment: My bad, haven't read the Mac OSX part. Apt is a ubuntu thing. Have you had a look at this? http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: I ended up removing `apt-get`, and it solved the problem.

Comment: Can you post an answer with that? Your last comment is not particularly clear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `apt-get` was the first in `ruby-install`'s package manager detection order. It was broken on my system, and this is why the error.

After I removed `apt-get` from my system, `ruby-install` picked up Homebrew and the error disappeared.