# How to uninstall apt-get on OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, apt-get

Is `apt-get` part of the OSX?

If not, what would be the easiest way to uninstall it from the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt-get is a debian package manager, there is no way to use this on mac.. (well no good way or point of using it because all the packages would fail to install even if you managed to get apt-get to install)

Use MacPorts or Homebrew...

Comment: My original problem is that `apt-get` is called when I do `brew install ruby-install`. Can you explain why it's being called? I'll appreciate your help! See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22403376/247243

Comment: I have no idea how apt got onto your Mac!!! it should not be there, the only way this could have happened is if it came bundled with some other package which compiled apt onto your mac... or if you downloaded and compiled it yourself...?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how it got there either. I just wonder what's the safest way to uninstall it.

Comment: Well unfortunately, you will have to figure out how it got there to be able to uninstall it.. if it was compiled, you will have to find the source and run such like `make clean` and `sudo make distclean` possibly `make uninstall`

Answer (score 2):

Try using brew install/uninstall pkg; For example:

```
brew uninstall apt-get
```

These commands might prove useful:

```
brew list                  # list all installed packages
brew search partial-name   # search for available packages
brew info pkg-name         # get information about a package
```